# Linux "install" command for wildcard installation

Tags: linux, installation

Is there a way to use "[install](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install)" for installing multiple files at once using a "wildcard" pattern (and still have "install" create the leading directory hierarchy)?

I've tried several different ways:

- `install -D -t /dest/path /source/path/*.py`
- `install -D -t /dest/path/ /source/path/*.py`
- `install -D /source/path/*.py /dest/path`
- `install -D /source/path/*.py /dest/path/`

Please help... for each trial it takes a lot of time (I am using `pbuilder` to test my package each time).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe use a simple outer for loop around the install call? So how about

```
for f in /source/path/*.py; do \
    install -D -t /dest/path $f; \
done
```

That said, you can always take the logic out of your Makefile, debian/rules file, ... and test it standalone without having to run `pbuilder`.

Otherwise of course props for using `pbuilder` for internal projects!

Comment: +1: Thanks. I could of course use your technique but I just found by repeated trial & error a working solution. Cheers.

Comment: @Dirk: I'll accept your answer even though I went for a more direct solution IMO. But hey, there are many ways to go about it. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, you response is pretty good too. Do you actually create .deb packages?  In that case dh_installdirs is super-easy -- just list what directories you need and you're done. Debhelper has many useful tools.

Answer (score 16):

Use the following to create the directory hierarchy, before installing:

```
install -d /dest/path
```

and then use:

```
install -D /source/path/*.py /dest/path
```

to "install" all the files.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the `-D` flag to create the destination path's leading parent directories? If they're already created with a previous `install` invocation, then it seems unnecessary to use it in the later command. Can you justify its use or is it safe to assume it can be removed in this instance?

Comment: `install` does not understand wildcards.   The solutions using `find` or `for` are the ways to work around this limitation.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know anything about pbuilder, but for my case (PKGBUILD for Arch Linux) I'm using a BASH for-loop with find:

```
for file in $(find source -type f -name *.py); do
    install -m 644 -D ${file} dest/${file#source/}
done
```

The find command can be suited to taste to be more or less specific about what gets copied. In the above example all regular files ending in .py anywhere below source/ would be selected.

Comment: This is the best way to do it if you want to have the equivalent of 'cp -r ...' using install. If you just want to copy the entire source directory structure (instead of only getting *.py), just leave off the '-name *.py'.

Comment: Even better, you can use `$(cd source && find -type f -name *.py)` to avoid bashism in the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, maybe I'm reviving an old post, but I think it's worth for future research. From the example given by [nharward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438506/nharward) (I also use arch linux and PKGBUILD), I modified so that I did not have to worry about the mode/permissions (-m) of the file, regardless of the directory structure.

```bash
for file in $(find ${srcdir} -type f); do
    install -m $(stat -c%a ${file}) -D ${file} ${pkgdir}/${file#${srcdir}}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

man install shows that the DEST must be existing if copy multiple files.

...
    In the first three forms, copy SOURCE to DEST or **multiple SOURCE(s) to the existing DIRECTORY**, while setting permission modes and owner/group. In the 4th form, create all components of the given DIRECTORY(ies).
...